# How to print out to a file using Stanford Classifier

Tags: nlp, classification, stanford-nlp, supervised-learning

I am using [Stanford Classifier](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml) for my project.
This project takes training data to tune the algorithm then test data to classify text inputs into categories.
So the format for test and training data is tab-delimited text which means predictor `-TAB- input text`
The software prints out the output to `stdout` (command line).
Is there anyway to output to a text file ? 
I searched the [javadoc](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html) of the project site, and I found [image: this one]

But I don't know how to use this property.
I tried `-csvoutput=%1%n%c` on command line
But it gives me java null pointer exception error when I try to run it.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the [tag:processing] language? You're going to have to provide much more information. Can you please post a [mcve] that shows exactly what you're doing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing, I added some mor details.

Comment: You didn't really answer my questions though. Are you using the [tag:processing] language? Can you provide a [mcve] that we can run?

Comment: Actually I dont know what you mean by processing language, I searched on Google could not find anything useful.

Comment: You tagged it with the [tag:processing] tag, which is for questions about the Processing language. The tag has since been removed, so it's a moot point. Your question is still very broad, so you probably aren't going to get very many replies. You need to post your code, preferably as a [mcve]. But it's up to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save it to a file just add this to the end of your command:

```
> output_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, you saved me from tons of problem.